# Don't show Page 403 - forbidden: Access is denied when posting to IIS

Tags: c#, angular, iis

I have a problem publishing my project that I am doing in **`ANGULAR 8`** and **`C# MVC Web API`** in **`IIS`**.

The point is that when I delete the files from the **`IIS`** server, to be able to put the new ones with the new version this screen appears for the users that are using in the application:

[image]

I would like this not to come out to the user, I would like some image or message to come out but I don't know how to control it, is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can use an interceptor that will do a redirect to specific view on all 403 error codes.  This article explains the idea... https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: Excellent, ok I'll check and tell you

Comment: You can also setup custom error pages through IIS as an option https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2008/05/27/iis-7-0-http-error-pages/

Comment: @nullptr.t, I didn't know what could be done thanks, I will also review this option

Comment: @nullptr.t Add it as an answer to mark it, it worked excellent thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution, as I said in the comment to add the answer to mark it as accepted, but it was not done, I have decided to do it myself,

The first thing I did was to enter my **`IIS`** and search the **sites by Default**, then enter **`Error Page`** in which select error **403** and Edit the visible view if this error occurs.

I hope it helps.